# Any way to resolve incomplete enum objects from lazy loads

Tags: java, enums, lazy-loading

Short question: Is there a way to fully load a class when anything inside of the class is referenced? Class.forName(...) isn't doing it and I'd prefer not to come up with a kludgey workaround (as shown below) that doesn't actually solve the issue.

Detailed question/scenario: I have some basic enum definitions:

```
public class V_Type
{
public static interface Datatype
    {
    public boolean Allow (Object pCandidate) ;
    }

public static enum Domain_y {A,I,N,T;
    public Datatype CoreDatatype ;
    }

public static enum String_y implements Datatype
    {
    Text    (null   ,Domain_y.T)
    ,Alpha  (Text   ,Domain_y.A)
    ;
    String_y (Datatype pParent, Domain_y pDomain)
        {
        V_Type.Index.Register(this, pParent, pDomain) ;
        }
    public boolean Allow (Object pCandidate) {return true;}
    }

public static enum Decimal_y implements Datatype
    {
    Notational  (String_y.Alpha ,Domain_y.N)
    ,Fractional (Notational     ,null)
    ;
    Decimal_y (Datatype pParent, Domain_y pDomain)
        {
        V_Type.Index.Register(this, pParent, pDomain) ;
        }
    public boolean Allow (Object pCandidate) {return true;/*TODO : Validate decimal data*/}
    }

public static enum Integer_y implements Datatype
    {
    Expressive  (Decimal_y.Fractional   ,Domain_y.I)
    ,Conversive (Expressive             ,null)
    ;
    Integer_y (Datatype pParent, Domain_y pDomain)
        {
        V_Type.Index.Register(this, pParent, pDomain) ;
        }
    public boolean Allow (Object pCandidate) {return true;/*TODO : Validate integer data*/}
    }

}
```

It's basically just a group of taxonomy objects. All of the enums are linked together through the V_Type.Index.Register call in each of the constructors. The Integer_y enum links up to the Decimal_y enum and the Decimal_y enum references the String_y enum. Each of the enum types has differing behaviors for handling data (such as the Allow methods noted above) which is why the process was split up between differing types. For the sake of brevity I haven't included the code because it's not part of the issue. In testing I've confirmed that all of the items join together as expected (with the kludge included, as I'll clarify below).

Then, on the testing page I have this:

```
public class x_LazyHiccup
{
public static void List (ArrayList<V_Type.Datatype> pDatatypes, String pLevel)
    {
    for (V_Type.Datatype oDatatype : pDatatypes)
        {
        System.out.println(pLevel + oDatatype.toString());
        ArrayList<V_Type.Datatype> oDatatypes = V_Type.Index.Children(oDatatype) ;
        List (oDatatypes, pLevel + "\t") ;
        }
    }

public static void main (String [] pArgs)
    {
    V_Type.LoadTaxonomy() ;

    List(V_Type.Index.Top(), "");
    }

}
```

This runs through the taxonomy and reports that all of the enums are joined together as the following:

```
Text

    Alpha

        Notational

            Fractional

                Expressive

                    Conversive
```

i.e. it's a hierarchy and all of the parent/child relationships are in proper form. BUT, the only reason why this works is because of this method:

```
public static void LoadTaxonomy ()
    {
    if (Integer_y.Conversive == null) ; // Do nothing. Just forces the bottom state into existence
    }
```

By referencing the bottommost enum, all of the enums are constructed and properly chained together. Without this test however, the lazy loading process doesn't load any of the enums at all, even though I'm referencing objects and methods in the class, it only loads the items that are referenced. If the LoadTaxonomy method is changed to:

```
public static void LoadTaxonomy ()
    {
    if (Decimal_y.Notational == null) ;
    }
```

the full hierarchy is gone:

```
Text

    Alpha

        Notational

            Fractional
```

i.e. the integer enum isn't there until it has been referenced by something.

Is there anything that can be done for this by the class itself? I need to know that all of the enums are loaded together in a consistent and synchronized way. I tried this in the class definition and it does absolutely nothing:

```
static
    {
    LoadTaxonomy() ; // Nope, not going to happen
    }
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Indent it properly.

Comment: @JB Nizet - sorry if this is "unreadable" to you. What indentation paradigm works for you so you can understand it?

Comment: Any of the standard ones. All use indentation to show what is under what. In your scheme, you have children on the same line, or on the same indentation level, as their parent, which is extremely confusing. Every IDE allows formatting a whole file in one mouse click or keyboard shortcut. Use this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own classloader, but I think it whould be the wrong approach. In my eyes, you should separate the definitions of types and registry. Without knowledge of the taxonomy domain and the usage at last, I would solve/design this by polymorphism, not with enums.